# User input table that takes percentages?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 Columns in a table. "Activities" and "Average % of Time", For every activity,I want the user to input the % value in the "Average % of Time" Column, I have 7 Activity rows. All I want is the % values of all the 7 fields to add to 100% and only then submit button gets active...
Anybody know How to go about this.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
HRG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tie a javascript onkeyup event on all the input fields.

Whenever it's triggered, add up the values of all the fields.

If it's 100, enable the button, else leave it disabled.

Are you using jQuery or raw Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

you should attach the keyup event to each input and add their values up.

```
$("input[type!='submit']").keyup(function () {
   count();
});

function count(){
   var total = 0;
    $("input[type!='submit']").each (function () {
        total+= parseInt($(this).val() || 0); 
    });

    if (total === 100) {
        $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr('disabled', '');   
    } else {
        $("input[type='submit']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VTq2v/1/